# Vue.JS - Is there a way to fire my tooltip component via a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tooltip, vue-component

From a anchor tag needs to be fired a method which will display (or hide) a tooltip with dynamic content.

I need a nudge in the right direction on how to get this done.

My first tooltip used a tooltip trigger which in turn fired the actual tooltip. This worked perfectly. The problem is that this needs to be integrated in a CMS where the user can only add anchor tags instead of Vue.js components.

I've set up the method that gets some information but I can't seem to figure out how this method will be able to load the component next to the anchor tag

This is what I currently have :

https://jsfiddle.net/AmmarAon/9gLerv0b/

```
<a  href="#" 
    class="tooltipTriggerMarkup"
    @click="fireTooltip('reference','Hallo dit is een titel','body')">
    Tooltip trigger
</a>
```

This is what I used to have (click on the links)

https://jsfiddle.net/AmmarAon/zwnv1oge/337/

```
<tooltipTrigger 
    :transition="'bounce'" 
    :reference="'tooltip1'"
    :tooltip-title="'This is the first tooltip!'" 
    :tooltip-body="'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'">
    Tooltip trigger
</tooltipTrigger>
```

So basically it needs to work the same way but with an anchor tag instead of a component

I would love to know if I need to build this idea from scratch or if this code is still salvagable (and how).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. With an anchor tag I can call a method which hides and shows the component. The component is basically a div which is in the main component. See an example here :

method call :

```
<a href="#" 
   class="tooltipTriggerMarkup"
   @click="fireTooltip('t2',
                       'Dit is de 2e tooltip',
                       'body body body')">commodo</a>
```

the method :

```
fireTooltip(reference,title,body) {
            this.showToolTip=!this.showToolTip;
            this.tooltipTitle = title;
            this.tooltipBody = body;
            this.reference = reference;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/AmmarAon/9gLerv0b/173/

because of the method the tooltip can be loaded with dynamic content. It also places the tooltip beneath the anchor tag and checks if the tooltip doesn't fall out of bounds of the window.